# Why AWS Lambda Internel Server Error 500 but successfully /invocations POST 200 in Endpoint SageMaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker

```
import os
import io
import boto3
import json
import csv


# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
# grab runtime client
runtime = boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Load data from POST request
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    
    # Grab the payload
    payload = data['body']
    
    # Invoke the model. In this case the data type is a JSON but can be other things such as a CSV
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                   ContentType='application/json',
                                   Body=payload)
    
    # Get the body of the response from the model
    result = response['Body'].read().decode()

    # Return it along with the status code of 200 meaning this was succesful 
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': result
    }
```

**response from AWS Lambda**

```
{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      18,
      "lambda_handler",
      "payload = data['body']"
    ]
  ]
}
```

[response from Postman 500 Internal Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8wvA.png)

[but successfully invoke POST 200 in SageMaker Endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuknX.png)

Comment: The event data that gets passed to Lambda is already deserialised. There was no point to serialize it again. I suggest you print out the event object and see how you can access the key you need for your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when you are trying to parse your payload with data['body']. The data is not being passed in the format that the endpoint is expecting. Use the following code snippet to properly format/serialize your data for the endpoint. Also to make all this clearer make sure to check for your payload type to make sure you have not serialized again by accident.

```
    data = json.loads(json.dumps(event))
    payload = json.dumps(data)
    response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,
                                       ContentType='application/json',
                                       Body=payload)
    result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
```

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own